# Can see multicast packets with TCPdump/Wireshark but cannot receive it in application

Tags: linux, networking, multicast

I have a Centos 7 server with 6 nics. I have two of them connected to different LANs -  ens20f3 (my home LAN) enp130s0f0 (for accessing a different network). I need to read multicast packets that are being received on enp130s0f0. If I do a `tcpdump -i enp130s0f0 -n` I can see multicast packets being received by the interface.

But when I try to read packets in my test python application, I cannot read anything. I have checked that I join the correct group using `netstat -gn`. I have disabled rp_filter. I even tried putting the interface in promiscuous mode as suggested in one post. I have tested that my python application on a different machine and it is working fine.

```
MYPORT = 10872
MYGROUP_4 = '239.50.50.72'

import time
import struct
import socket
import sys

def main():
group = MYGROUP_4
# Look up multicast group address in name server and find out IP version
addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(group, None)[0]`
# Create a socket
s = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Allow multiple copies of this program on one machine
# (not strictly needed)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind it to the port
s.bind(('', MYPORT))

group_bin = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])
# Join group
if addrinfo[0] == socket.AF_INET: # IPv4
    mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('=I', socket.INADDR_ANY)
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
else:
    mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('@I', 0)
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

# Loop, printing any data we receive
while True:
    data, sender = s.recvfrom(1500)
    while data[-1:] == '\0': data = data[:-1] # Strip trailing \0's
    print (str(sender) + '  ' + repr(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

My routing table is as follows:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.230.47.129   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp130s0f0
10.230.47.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     100    0        0 enp130s0f0
172.19.0.0      10.230.47.129   255.255.0.0     UG    100    0        0 enp130s0f0
192.168.110.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens20f3
```

The tcp dump output looks like this:

```
17:30:24.444744 IP 172.19.250.28.56915 > 239.100.39.25.10225: UDP, length 56
```

Hence the entries corresponding to `172.19.*.*`

Any pointers to what I can look for to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Turns out firewall was blocking the packets.

```
service firewalld stop
```

This did the trick.